# Xamarin Forms: Using the same command from a button and onAppearing does not work

Tags: xamarin, command

I am trying to auto-login the user when starting the app. Therefore I created the following command in my ViewModel:

```
public Command LoginCommand { get; private set; }

public LoginViewModel()
{
    LoginCommand = new Command(async () => await Login());
}
```

The XAML Code looks like this:

```
<Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Style="{StaticResource LoginButton}"/>
```

So this works well as long as I am not using the same command of the Bindingcontext within the onAppearing method of the corresponding page:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if (LoginVM.AutoLogin)
    {
        LoginVM.LoginCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

What happens is that as soon as the page appears, the Login procedure gets executed correctly. However if the login fails (e.g. because of a timeout), **nothing happens if I click the login button again**.

The interesting part is that if I add a "Clicked" event handler to the button and execute the LoginCommand manually from there, it works.

Can somebody tell me, why the code behaves like this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: StaticResources means do not need to change the value of the resource after the first reference.Did you do some judgement after call the method login?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for not responding earlier.
What do you mean by "Judgement"?